# Getting "Invlaid expression" when trying to find elements within a named element in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, element

I’m using Nokogiri with Ruby on Rails 4.2.7.  How do I say that I want to find all “option” elements within another element with the name of “range”?  I tried

```
response = http.request(req)
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)
…
options = doc.xpath(“//range option")
```

but it is giving me the error

```
Error during processing: Invalid expression: //range option
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb:165:in `evaluate'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb:165:in `block in xpath'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb:156:in `map'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". You don't have a minimal example of the input HTML which would help us help you. Making us cobble up same HTML wastes our time which could go toward helping others. Are you actually trying to parse XML as HTML?

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you want, but this might help.

Meditate on this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML('<root><range><option>1</option><option>2</option></range></root>')

doc.search('range option') # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ffc64544e1c name="option" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ffc64544c3c "1">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ffc64544a5c name="option" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ffc6454487c "2">]>]
doc.search('range option').map(&:to_xml) # => ["<option>1</option>", "<option>2</option>"]
```

`search` will walk the document and return all matching elements for the selector. The CSS `range option` looks for all `<range>` containing `<option>` tags and returns the `<option>` nodes in a NodeSet. From that point you can fold, spindle or mutilate to your heart's content.

Comment: When I say "element with the name of 'range'", I mean an element that has an attribute called "name" that is equal to "range".  Does that make sense?

Comment: That information needs to be added to your question as if you'd written it there initially. Don't use "Edit" or "Update" tags in the text as we can tell what changed when if we want to know. A minimal HTML sample demonstrating what you're talking about makes a lot more sense than a description of it; A picture is worth a thousand words.